# AS3 GoViral ANE - native login window?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, ane

i tried out the GoViral ANE from www.milkmangames.com.

It is working fine so far, but I'm wondering how to use the native login function!

Facebook do not allow this "webview"-based login window anymore.

The ANE description says:

> - Native Facebook dialogs and UI with the Official Facebook iOS SDK
> - 100% Native solution for iOS, Android, or Both

But with the Facebook SDK you'll not get this webview login-popup, but a confirmation popup for using the smartphone configured facebook account.

Is there a option for using this kind of login?
Facebook will not accept my app using the webview login.
I tried it a several times.

[image: Facebooks response]

**USING:**
Flex 4.14.0
AIR 16.0
iOS 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well!

I just fixed this issue by myself.

It seems, there was something wrong in the Facebook application settings!

> Set "Client OAuth Login" to "NO"
>
> Set "Embedded browser OAuth Login" to "NO"
>
> Set "Native or desktop app?" to "YES"

Its working well now!